# Is downcasting this during construction safe?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static-cast

I have a class hierarchy where I know that a given class (B) will always be derived into a second one (D). In B's constructor, is it safe to statically cast the `this` pointer into a D* if I'm sure that nobody will ever try to use it before the entire construction is finished? In my case, I want to pass a reference to the object to yet another class (A).

```
struct A
{
    D & d_;

    A(D & d) : d_(d) {}
};

struct D; //forward declaration

struct B
{
    A a;

    B() : a(std::static_cast<D&>(*this)) {}
};

struct D : public B
{};
```

Is this code safe?

Comment: This raises the question of what value class D is adding, if B is *always* a D.

Comment: B is a class template that defines or not a member function based on its template parameter. There are several class templates like that, which are then inherited by D to provide an interface dependent on the template parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@AProgrammer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193134/is-downcasting-this-during-construction-safe/1193245#1193245) made me realized that the `static_cast` could be easily avoided by passing the `this` pointer from the derived class to the base class. Consequently, the question boils down to the validity of the `this` pointer into the member-initializer-list.

I found the following note in the C++ Standard [12.6.2.7]:

> [*Note:* because the *mem-initializer* are evaluated in the scope of the constructor, the `this` pointer can be used in the *expression-list* of a *mem-initializer* to refer to the object being initialized. ]

Therefore, using `this` in the member-initializer-list is perfectly valid, so I think the code presented is safe (as long as no members of D are accessed).

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not. Constructors for D's data members didn't run yet.

Since D's membrs aren't constructed, D isn't fully constructed yet, so technically, a reference to D should be invalid. I expect that to be no problem on most implementations, but still.

I'd like to suggest a better mechanism, but I guess "better" depends a lot on actual details.

Comment: I know that D hasn't been constructed yet, that's why I precised that none of its member will be accessed before construction is over.

Comment: Regarding the validity of the this pointer in the initializer list, I also remember reading somewhere that it was unsafe to use it, but is it still true if no members are accessed? I'll try to find the paragraph in the standard that can answer this question.

Comment: Apparently, the standard explicitly states that 'this' can be used in the member-initializer-list to refer to the object being constructed.

Comment: I can't dig it up again, but I also can't reproduce it - I *think* the scenario was a bit different, maybe initializing a reference in the base class to a member in the derived class. Anyway, I'm removing the IIRC part, it's misleading. Thanks, Luc!

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find anything about that.  I've trouble to find reasons for which your code would be unsafe while this is safe:

```
struct B
{
    A a;

    B(D& d) : a(d) {}
};

struct D : public B
{
    D() : B(*this) {}
};
```

but I'd probably still use the form I present here.

Comment: That's a nice way to avoid the static_cast, but the problem about the validity of this in the initializer list still holds. +1 for the cleaner way of writing it though.